# Prevent Meteor.js from Restarting on Error

Tags: node.js, meteor

When Meteor.js is started using the `mrt` command, it automatically restarts the app 3 times when an error occurs.

Is it possible to avoid restarting on error (just let the error crash and exit the process), or change the number of times Meteor will attempt the restart.

Comment: this happens only in development mode. If you actually bundle the app to the production mode and run it as a regular node app it will not restart on errors

Comment: @imslavko Thank you, thats good to know. I would like to prevent the auto-restart in dev mode too

Answer (score 1):

You need to catch the errors and handle them if you want it to work this way.

You can't prevent a syntax error from stopping meteor restarting though, because it can't start in the first place!

Meteor automatically stops apps from crashing provided the errors occur in `Meteor.startup()`, `Meteor.methods`, or `Meteor.publish`

If you have 'free hanging code' that isn't in any of those you need to handle it with try and catch i.e

```
try {

    //Somewhere the errors always come from

}
catch(e) {
    //Report the error?
    console.log(e.message);
}
```

If you don't want to catch it you'll need to run the code in any of the Meteor closures (Meteor.methods, Meteor.publish, Meteor.startup, Meteor.setTimeout, Meteor.setInterval).

If you have any external modules or something that runs that is in a method that is asynchronous you need to make sure that it runs within the same Fiber, with `Meteor.bindEnvironment` or `Meteor._wrapAsync` (usually for npm modules) so that the error occurs where it originated from and not on its own.